# Python notebook fail to load properly

Tags: ipython

I am using the Anaconda 2.76 version. It was working fine until today. The notebook page was not loaded properly. Noe of the feature was responsive. After I did some research, I think it is some coding error, but since I am really not a computing kind of guy, I don't know where exactly went wrong and how to fix it. Below is the error message I received. please lend me a hand. Thanks a lot.

```
HTTPRequest (protocol=’http’, host =’127.0.0.1:8888;,method=’GET’,uri=’/static/base/images/favicon.ico’,version=’HTTP/1.1’,remote_ip-‘127.0.0.1’,headers={‘connection’:’keep-alive’,’Accept-Language’:’zh-CN,zh;q=0.8,en;q=0.6,zh-TW;q=0.4’,’Accept-Encoding’:’gzip,deflate,sdch’,'host’:'127.0.0.1:8888’,Accept':'*/*','User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0(windows NT 6.1; WOW64)AppleWebKit/537.36(KHTML,like Gecko)Chrome/34.0.1847.131 Safari/537.36'})

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "D:|Anaconda\lib\site-packages\tornado\web.py", line 1218, in _when_complete
callback()
File "D:|Anaconda\lib\site-packages\tornado\web.py", Line 1239, in _execute_method
self._when_coplete(method(*self.path_args,**self.path_kwargs),
File "D:|Anaconda\lib\site-packages\IPython\html\base\handlers.py", line 318, in get
mime_type, encoding=mimetypes.guess_type(abspath)
File "D:\Anaconda\lib\mimetypes.py", line 297, in guess_type
init()
File "D:\Anaconda\lib\mimetypes.py", line 358,in init
db.read_windows_registry()
File "D:\Anaconda\lib\mimetypes.py", line 258,in read_windows_registry
for subkeyname in enum_types(hkcr):
File "D:\Anaconda\lib\mimetypes.py", line 249,in enum_types
ctype=ctype.encode(default_encoding)#omit in 3.X!
UnicodeDecodeError: "ascii" codec can't decode byte 0*b0 in position 1:ordinal not in range(128)
2014-5-12 16:43:45.456 [tornado.access] ERROR |500 GET /static/base/images/favicon.ico (127.0.0.1) 97.00ms`
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a [known issue](http://bugs.python.org/issue9291).

I've solved the same problem using the following temporary modification of  Anaconda/Lib/mimetypes.py, lines 252-253 (as proposed [here](http://bugs.python.org/issue9291#msg217137)).

```
try:
  ctype = ctype.encode(default_encoding) # omit in 3.x!
except UnicodeEncodeError:
  pass
except Exception: #<--
  pass            #<--
else:
  yield ctype
```